# Checkstyle Java generics: '?' is not preceded with whitespace

Tags: java, generics, whitespace, wildcard, checkstyle

I am using plugin

```xml
<artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.17</version>
```

It has 6.11.2 checkstyle version. Configuration saying about whitespaces is:

```xml
<module name="NoWhitespaceAfter">
    <property name="severity" value="error" />
    <property name="tokens" value="ARRAY_INIT,BNOT,DEC,DOT,INC,LNOT" />
</module>
<module name="NoWhitespaceBefore">
    <property name="severity" value="error" />
</module>
<module name="RedundantModifier">
    <property name="severity" value="error" />
</module>
<module name="WhitespaceAround">
    <property name="severity" value="error" />
    <property name="tokens" value="ASSIGN,BAND,BAND_ASSIGN,BOR,BOR_ASSIGN,BSR,BSR_ASSIGN,BXOR,BXOR_ASSIGN,COLON,DIV,DIV_ASSIGN,DO_WHILE,EQUAL,GE,LAND,LCURLY,LE,LITERAL_ASSERT,LITERAL_CATCH,LITERAL_DO,LITERAL_ELSE,LITERAL_FINALLY,LITERAL_FOR,LITERAL_IF,LITERAL_RETURN,LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED,LITERAL_TRY,LITERAL_WHILE,LOR,MINUS,MINUS_ASSIGN,MOD,MOD_ASSIGN,NOT_EQUAL,PLUS,PLUS_ASSIGN,RCURLY,SL,SLIST,SL_ASSIGN,SR,SR_ASSIGN,STAR,STAR_ASSIGN,TYPE_EXTENSION_AND" />
</module>
```

I always get this error:

```
(whitespace) WhitespaceAround: WhitespaceAround: '?' is not preceded with whitespace.  
(whitespace) WhitespaceAround: WhitespaceAround: '?' is not followed by whitespace.
Empty blocks may only be represented as {} when not part of a multi-block statement (4.1.3)
```

The code snippets are:

```java
Class<?>[] groups() default {};  
Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
```

I tried to remove the snippet with whitespaces, but still get the same error.

Comment: Could it be that it is interpreting `Class[]` as `Class<?>[]`?

Comment: @Kiskae it is OK when I do it like this:      Class< ? >[] groups() default {};

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug in checkstyle, it has been fixed in [Checkstyle 6.14](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/releasenotes.html#Release_6.14) (see https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/2633)

You can upgrade checkstyle by adding a `<dependencies>` section in the maven-checkstyle-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
            <version>6.14</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Or you can go straight to the newest Checkstyle (7.0).

Comment: it doesn't help. Version 6.14 still gets the same error. Version 7.x requires for Java 8, but we use JDK 7 in our project. Any other ideas?

Comment: And it is quite strange because it should have a fix for your exact case.

Comment: I just did the same thing and I also get the same errors for 6.14. I suspect that this is down to configuration issues, that are not part of the answer.

Comment: @mirabilos Maybe there is a regression in 8.4

Comment: I have the same issue with Checkstyle 7.6. It looks like whitespace rules are conflicting with generic rule.